# syntax error on tokens delete these tokens android

Tags: java, android

I am building an android application, but it is giving me the above error; when I use 4 variable declarations In the below code?

```
package com.example.rssreader;

import java.io.Serializable;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String _title = null;
private String _description = null;
private String _date = null;



public class RSSItem implements Serializable{

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: Declaration must be inside class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Move your declarations inside class you can declare variables inside class or interface right now your declarations are in **air**.*

```
public class RSSItem implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private String _title = null;
  private String _description = null;
  private String _date = null;
```